# How to protect JSON API from being accessed by anyone but my iOS client?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api

I have an iPhone app that uses a Rails server HTTP API. The API is public at this point - no authorisation is required to get the data.

Currently anyone can go to API's URL and download the data.

```
http://server.com/mydata
```

The data is not very sensitive. But I still want to prevent people from easily getting it. What are the ways of doing that? I do not want iOS app users to log in either.

#### Current solution I have

iPhone app adds a secret token to the HTTP header or query of the request. The data goes over HTTPS.

```
https://server.com/mydata?secret=my_secret
```

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try an approach where the client is only allowed X number of requests per time period (based on IP address or username)

HTTPS is extremely easy to man in the middle on a device you control. You can do SSL cert validation, but there is always someone out there with more time, so best off to handle it server side.

Answer (score 2):

[Distribute and use your own SSL certificate](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-https-certificate-handling-to-protect-your-ios-app/).

> Apps that transfer sensitive customer data, like credit card and payment information, must be protected from man-in-the middle attacks. *The best protection is a mutual authentication scheme, where certificates are exchanged to make sure the app is connected to a trusted server and to make sure the server is connected to a trusted app.*

Then only individuals (who have presumably installed your application) have access. If someone digs through the code and gets the public certificate then they can impersonate the client; but at that point they win anyway and two-factor authentication should be explored.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for information. Stupid question - does the self-signed SSL certificate provide better security from **scraping the data from server** than my approach of just passing a secret token in HTTPS request? Here all I want to prevent is craping data from server. I am not worried if connection is compromised and iOS app starts getting data from **other** server instead.

Comment: @Evgeny As long as the device *doesn't* have a compromised CA chain then HTTPS (TLS1.1+, with vulnerabilities fixed) can be considered a secure encrypted channel. As such a shared secret that is sent over can be considered secret over that connection. A MitM attack is not feasible unless the [CA trust is compromised](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server).

Comment: @Evgeny For a self-signed certificate it must be trusted explicitly; needless to say, SSL using an *untrusted* certificate does not have the same guarantees.